# Is there a better way to print out my object in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

Here's what I got right now:

```
$results = DB::select('select * from test_table');
$result= json_decode(json_encode($results), true);

$x=0;
try {
    while ($x<10)
    {
        echo $result[$x]['column_A'];
        echo " ";
        echo $result[$x]['column_B'];
        echo "<br>";
        $x++;
    }
}
catch(exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

which echos out:

```
179368 3A
176733 3B
686733 3C
178673 3D
168663 3E
937338 3F
936888 58
186335 59
199366 5A
159373 5B
```

So far I know that I could switch out `while` with a `for` loop to make things slightly shorter. Is there another method of printing out certain rows that looks better than this?

EDIT: By the way, I'm using Laravel if that means anything.

EDIT 2: So is there a way I could print this out without knowing the names of the columns?

Thanks!

Comment: Prettier? Too vague.

Comment: try: echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);

Comment: Add html tags and style it whatever way you want.

Comment: @JonStirling, updated. Is it still too vague?

Comment: PHP objects can also be traversed naturally by [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach). Though I suspect based on the DB context here what you have is just an array of objects so there's certainly no need for the json_encode/decode step there and `foreach` is the better construct.

Comment: Please consider reading [this answer on how the `foreach` construct works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14854568/1878262) as reference to your *Edit 2*.

Answer (score -2):

Shorter would be with the use of `foreach()` for iterating and `printf()`for echo'ing the values. You can also use `sprintf()` to store the string into a variable.

```
$results = DB::select('select * from test_table');
$result= json_decode(json_encode($results), true);

foreach ($result as $row) {
    printf('%s %s<br/>', $row['column_A'], $row['column_B']);
}
```